# Dynamically calling a SQL Server stored procedure from a C# application

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a class (`dbConnections`) with methods for handling types of DB queries.  I would like to make calls to a method in this class passing the name of the procedure and an array containing the required parameters for that particular call.

However when executed, it doesn't recognise that any parameters have been passed. If I hard-code them, they work fine so there is obviously something wrong with my application of the loop.

I want to be able to re-use this method passing and getting differing parameters, I just don't know how I should be going about it. I haven't tackled the return parameters yet as I haven't got this working...

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

This is the method in my `dbConnections` class:

```
public void ExecuteProcedure(string procedureName, string[] paramName, string[] procParams)
{
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procedureName, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        for (int i = 0; i >= paramName.Length; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName[i], procParams[i]);
        }

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

This is a calling method:

```
private void btn_logIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          
        string uid = txb_userId.Text;
        string pwd = txb_password.Text;
        string procedureName = "spUsers_Login";
        string[] paramName = new string[2];
        string[] procParams = new string[2];

        paramName[0] = "@Username";
        procParams[0] = uid;
        paramName[1] = "@Password";
        procParams[1] = pwd;

        db.OpenConection();
        db.ExecuteProcedure(procedureName, paramName, procParams);
}
```

Comment: your `for` loop, do you want "<" or ">=" ?

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Do you checked what SQL query is  executing?
I believe  your SQL command  in the end build query that looks like this:
`exec procedureName  Value,Value ,Value `   instead of   `exec procedureName  @property=Value , @property2=Value , @property3=Value`

Answer (score 5):

First of all check your loop

```
for (int i = 0; i >= paramName.Length; i++)
```

It will never pass the condition, it should be `i<paramName.Length`

Answer (score 1):

Can you change the code like this

```
private void btn_logIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        string uid = txb_userId.Text;
        string pwd = txb_password.Text;
        string procedureName = "spUsers_Login @Username, @Password";
        string[] paramName = new string[2];
        string[] procParams = new string[2];

        paramName[0] = "@Username";
        procParams[0] = uid;
        paramName[1] = "@Password";
        procParams[1] = pwd;

        db.OpenConection();
        db.ExecuteProcedure(procedureName, paramName, procParams);
    }
```